# jQuery - Change value of dropdown when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the value of a dropdown when a link is clicked. I've done my due diligence and believe this can be done with 'prop' .. but I'm not sure how I'd use prop with my particular example. The code I was using up to now is...:

```
var $select = $('#finder-3--16');
$('a[href="#yearselect"]').click(function () {
    $select.val( $(this).data('select') );
});
```

On the click of a link, it sets the value but does not change it (therefore events binded to onchange are not triggered). An example of the link can be seen below...:

```
<a href="#yearselect" data-select="125921">2009</a>
```

I believe I have to return the value somehow and then use that, but not sure how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The onchange function can be seen here:

```
onChange: function(event)
{
    var select     = Event.element(event);
    var parentId   = select.value;
    var dropdownId = 0;

    /* should load next element's options only if current is not the last one */
    for (var i = 0; i < this.selects.length; i++){
        if (this.selects[i].id == select.id && i != this.selects.length-1){
            var selectToReload = this.selects[i + 1];
            if (selectToReload){
                dropdownId = selectToReload.id.substr(selectToReload.id.search('--') + 2);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you setup a JSFiddle of your code.

Comment: are you using preventDefault method in the anchor click to stop it from trying to another page?

Comment: Trigger the change event after: `$select.trigger( 'change' );`

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the events binded to the change of `select`, Try

```
$select.val( $(this).data('select') ).change();
```

or `.trigger('change')`

it will trigger the change event which will call your change callbacks..

Comment: This changed the value of the select field, but the onchange event was not triggered.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var $select = $('#finder-3--16');
$('a[href="#yearselect"]').click(function () {
    $select.val( $(this).attr('data-select') );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the change event after you've updated the value

```
var $select = $('#finder-3--16');
$('a[href="#yearselect"]').click(function () {
    $select.val( $(this).data('select') );
    $select.trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This has been updated to also trigger the change event.

I have created a fiddle to show you a working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ru3Md/10/

In a nutshell, what you need is this:

```
$(function() {
$('a').on('click',function(event) {

    var txt =  $(this).text();

    $('#mySelect option')
.filter(function() { return $.trim( $(this).text() ) == txt; })
.attr('selected',true).change();

})
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have the `value` attribute defined on your `<option>` tags.  Do this:

```
<select id="finder-3--16">
  <option value="125921">whatever label you want</option>
</select>
```

Now your existing jQuery should work.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X7SVe/